# Can modern SharePoint menu be customized

Tags: sharepoint-online, office-365, modern-pages

I am using modern SharePoint Online (office 365).

I have two questions:

- Is it possible to customize modern SharePoint menu (add headers, make some links **bold**, add horizontal lines etc.)
- Is it possible to customize modern SharePoint in general (mostly by adding custom CSS)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes, we can. The modern SharePoint online navigation works based on the mega menu and hub site. We need to properly set up the hub site and mega menu - then using the SPFx framework coding, we can customize the look and feel of the mega menu.

You may refer to the below articles, how does megamenu work in SharePoint online?

[Organize your SharePoint sites with megamenu navigation and new “change the look” options](https://techcommunity.microsoft.com/t5/microsoft-sharepoint-blog/organize-your-sharepoint-sites-with-megamenu-navigation-and-new/ba-p/328068)

[SharePoint Online Mega Menu](https://steveknutson.blog/2019/02/14/sharepoint-online-mega-menu/)

How to develop megamenu using the SPFx framework?

[Mega Menu using SharePoint Framework (SPFx) Extensions](https://ravichandran.blog/2019/04/14/mega-menu-using-sharepoint-framework-spfx-extensions/)

Comment: Your second link is broken.

Comment: Thanks, corrected

Comment: Thank you. Do you know the answer to my 2nd question: is it possible to add custom css in general?

Comment: Using the SPFx extension type of project we can customize the CSS of mega menu - you can refer the below example, how to work with megamenu using SPFx framework:https://ravichandran.blog/2019/04/14/mega-menu-using-sharepoint-framework-spfx-extensions/